# Advantages of pass-by-ref/val with impl IntoIterator<Item = impl AsRef<str>>

Tags: rust

In Rust, I often see functions accepting `impl IntoIter<...>` iterators, e.g.

```
pub fn foo(
    args: impl IntoIterator<Item = impl AsRef<str>>,
) -> usize {
    // any kind of processing goes here - like this, but could be totally different
    args.into_iter().map(|s| s.as_ref().len()).sum()
}
```

If a caller has the ownership of some collection, e.g. a `Vec`, it could call
`foo` in two ways (both compilable):

```
foo(args);
// or
foo(&args);
```

Are there any costs associated with pass-by-value in a case where a function can work with either?  I [tried comparing](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/naac4e9KG) generated assembly, and the referenced version does look longer, but I don't have sufficient assemby knowledge to evaluate which is actually better.

Comment: I also can't tell via assembly. Would be worth benchmarking.

Comment: @Finomnis I am a bit worried about benchmarking because the code inside `foo` might influence it too much. Clippy suggests to use by-val, but I would love to learn more about the `impl Into...` cases in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the type inferred by `impl IntoIterator`.

The Owned value (`foo(args)`) generate the struct `std::vec::IntoIter`, that simply "pop" values from the Vec.

The Borrowed value (`foo(&args)`) generate the type `std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>`, this one is just a slice that produces value by returning the first element, and advance the slice to the next position.

The difference is the second case having a extra de-reference from the first. I don't now why the assembly code generated from each case is so different, and life is too short to be spent analyzing x86_64 assembly :)

But you can notice that the compiled code for [armv7](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/EbT94Y4P4) and [i586](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/o8dohTnPc) is basically the same in both cases. This seems to indicate that there is little difference in those two implementations, and this seems to be a strange optimization that the compiler make exclusively for the x86_64 architecture.

Comment: thanks! Are there any preference towards transferring the ownership rather than by ref? Would that optimize better in a general case, or would that imply copying the whole value on heap?

Comment: It dependents a lot on the situation, but usually it makes little to no difference in performance. Generally programs pass the value/reference based if you want/need the value to be consumed or not. BTW only types impl `Copy` will be copied implicitly, otherwise you will need to explicitly call `clone`, so usually you don't need to worry about copies happening without you notice.